# How does readdir return a pointer to information for the NEXT file?

Tags: c, readdir

I'm learning C. so I'm just kinda confused about the function `readdir`. In the book K&R, the function `dirwalk` includes the following

```
while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL){
  if (strcmp(dp->name, ".") == 0
//...code...
```

Based on my understanding, each time the `while`loop is passed, `dp` (directory entry) is advanced one step, so next directory entry (which is associated with a file) can be processed (while `dp != NULL`)

My question is: How does`readdir` return a new directory entry each time it's called? Where does it show that? Please don't use too much jargon as I just started learning about this. Here's the code for `readdir`. Thanks.

```
#include <sys/dir.h>
Dirent *readdir(DIR *dp)
{
  struct direct dirbuf; \* local directory structure *\
  static Dirent d;
  while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf))
  == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
    if (dirbuf.d_ino == 0) \* slot not in use *\
      continue;
    d.ino = dirbuf.d_ino;
    strncpy(d.name, dirbuf.d_name, DIRSIZ);
    d.name[DIRSIZ] = '\0'; \* ensure termination *\
    return &d;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not the code that the POSIX `readdir` would use on any relevant operating system...

How the code works is really simple, assuming that you know how **files** work. A directory on the UNIX systems is just as readable a file as any other file would be - a directory would appear as if a binary file of directory records - in this implementation the `dirbuf` structure is one record in a directory. Therefore reading `sizeof dirbuf` bytes from the file descriptor gives you a next entry from the directory - the filename and its associated inode number.

If a file is deleted an entry might be marked unused by setting the inode number to 0, and it is skipped by the code.

When a next used entry is found, its filename and inode number is copied to the `Dirent d`, which has **static storage duration**. It means that there is only one `Dirent` allocated for use by `readdir` for the **entire duration** of the program. `readdir` will return **the same pointer** over and over again, pointing to the same structure, but the contents of the structure change.

Finally, when all entries in the directory have been read the last call to `readdir` will execute a `read` that will not read `sizeof (dirbuf)` bytes and the loop is broken, and `NULL` pointer is returned.

Comment: Re: "Reading ```sizeof dirbuf``` bytes gives you a next entry from the directory - the filename and its inode number." . How does reading ```fd``` (file descriptor?) give me a next entry?

Comment: You might want to add that the `Dirent` structure should be made part of the `DIR` structure to allow reentrancy. Of course different file systems and operating systems might require more advanced techniques beyond the scope of this question.